# I have got the same mistake frm PDO PHP

Tags: php, pdo, execute

```
I use PHP PDO to update my data n database, but htis nt work coretly i still recive te same errror: 
        Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number.
```

how cna i fix this?
             Hello I stil received this error but i can not find a mistake i made. when i throw away execute the code do not throw any error, but nothing change in my database.
            I create code that should update a data in database i still receives this error:

```
    I really want to now what make this error and hot to fixed i check with manual and everything look find, and i do not find any cntaradiction with my database in sql ask.


         <?php
session_start();
include 'polaczenie_baz_danych.php';
$id_faktury = $_POST['id_faktury'];
$id_sprzedawcy = $_POST['id_sprzedawcy'];
$id_nabywcy = $_POST['id_nabywcy'];
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$numer_faktury = $_POST['numer_faktury'];
$typ_faktury = $_POST['typ_faktury'];
$miejsce_wystawienia = $_POST['miejsce_wystawienia'];
$termin_wystawienia = $_POST['termin_wystawienia'];
$termin_sprzedazy= $_POST['termin_sprzedazy'];
$status_faktury = $_POST['status_faktury'];
$sposob_platnosci = $_POST['sposob_platnosci'];
$termin_platnosci = $_POST['termin_platnosci'];
$numer_konta =  $_POST['numer_konta'];
$towar_usluga = $_POST['towar_usluga'];
$jm = $_POST['jm'];
$ilosc = $_POST['ilosc'];
$cena_netto = $_POST['cena_netto'];
$wartosc_netto = $_POST['wartosc_netto'];
$stawka_vat = $_POST['stawka_vat'];
$kwota_vat = $_POST['kwota_vat'];
$wartosc_brutto = $_POST['wartosc_brutto'];

$nazwa_nabywcy = $_POST['nazwa_nabywcy'];
$nip_nabywcy  = $_POST['nip_nabywcy'];
$adres_nabywcy = $_POST['adres_nabywcy'];
$miasto_nabywcy = $_POST['miasto_nabywcy'];
$kod_pocztowy_nabywcy = $_POST['kod_pocztowy_nabywcy'];

$nazwa_sprzedawcy = $_POST['nazwa_sprzedawcy'];
$nip_sprzedawcy  = $_POST['nip_sprzedawcy'];
$adres_sprzedawcy = $_POST['adres_sprzedawcy'];
$miasto_sprzedawcy = $_POST['miasto_sprzedawcy'];
$kod_pocztowy_sprzedawcy = $_POST['kod_pocztowy_sprzedawcy'];  

$sql1 = ('UPDATE faktury SET 
typ_faktury=:typ_faktury, 
termin_wystawienia=:termin_wystawienia,
miejsce_wystawienia=:miejsce_wystawienia, 
numer_faktury=:numer_faktury, 
termin_sprzedazy=:termin_sprzedazy, 
towar_usluga=:towar_usluga, 
jm=:jm, 
ilosc=:ilosc,
cena_netto=:cena_netto, 
wartosc_netto=:wartosc_netto, 
stawka_vat=:stawka_vat, 
kwota_vat=:kwota_vat, 
wartosc_brutto=:wartosc_brutto, 
status_faktury=:status_faktury,
termin_platnosci=:termin_platnosci,
sposob_platnosci=:sposob_platnosci, 
numer_konta=:numer_konta 

WHERE id_faktury=:id_faktury');

$sql2 = ('UPDATE nabywcy SET nazwa_nabywcy=:nazwa_nabywcy,
 nip_nabywcy=:nip_nabywcy, 
 adres_nabywcy=:adres_nabywcy, 
 miasto_nabywcy=:miasto_nabywcy, 
 kod_pocztowy_nabywcy=:kod_pocztowy_nabywcy 
WHERE id_nabywcy=:id_nabywcy');

$sql3 =('UPDATE sprzedawcy SET nazwa_sprzedawcy=:nazwa_sprzedawcy, nip_sprzedawcy=:nip_sprzedawcy, adres_sprzedawcy=:adres_sprzedawcy, miasto_sprzedawcy=:miasto_sprzedawcy, kod_pocztowy_sprzedawcy=:kod_pocztowy_sprzedawcy
WHERE id_sprzedawcy=:id_sprzedawcy');

$performsql1 = $db->prepare($sql1);
$performsql1->bindValue(':typ_faktury',$typ_faktury, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$performsql1->bindValue(':termin_wystawienia',$termin_wystawienia, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$performsql1->bindValue(':miejsce_wystawienia',$miejsce_wystawienia, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$performsql1->bindValue(':numer_faktury',$numer_faktury, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$performsql1->bindValue(':termin_sprzedazy',$termin_sprzedazy, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$performsql1->bindValue(':towar_usluga', $towar_usluga, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$performsql1->bindValue(':jm',$jm, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$performsql1->bindValue(':ilosc',$ilosc, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$performsql1->bindValue(':cena_netto',$cena_netto, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$performsql1->bindValue(':wartosc_netto',($wartosc_netto), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$performsql1->bindValue(':stawka_vat',$stawka_vat, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$performsql1->bindValue(':kwota_vat',$kwota_vat, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$performsql1->bindValue(':wartosc_brutto',$wartosc_brutto, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$performsql1->bindValue(':sposob_platnosci',$sposob_platnosci, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$performsql1->bindValue(':status_faktury',$status_faktury, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$performsql1->bindValue(':termin_platnosci',$termin_platnosci, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$performsql1->bindValue(':numer_konta',$numer_konta, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$performsql1->bindValue(':id_faktury',$id_faktury, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$performsql1->execute();
unset($sql1);

$performsql2 = $db->prepare($sql2);
$performsql2->bindValue(':nazwa_nabywcy',$nazwa_nabywcy, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$performsql2->bindValue(':nip_nabywcy',$nip_nabywcy, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$performsql2->bindValue(':adres_nabywcy',$adres_nabywcy, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$performsql2->bindValue(':miasto_nabywcy',$miasto_nabywcy, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$performsql2->bindValue(':kod_pocztowy_nabywcy', $kod_pocztowy_nabywcy, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$performsql1->bindValue(':id_nabywcy',$id_nabywcy, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$performsql2->execute();
unset($sql2);
```

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

```
$performsql3 = $db->prepare($sql3);
$performsql3->bindValue(':nazwa_sprzedawcy',$nazwa_sprzedawcy, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$performsql3->bindValue(':nip_sprzedawcy',$nip_sprzedawcy, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$performsql3->bindValue(':adres_sprzedawcy',$adres_sprzedawcy, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$performsql3->bindValue(':miasto_sprzedawcy',$miasto_sprzedawcy, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$performsql3->bindValue(':kod_pocztowy_sprzedawcy', $kod_pocztowy_sprzedawcy, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$performsql1->bindValue(':id_sprzedawcy',$id_sprzedawcy, PDO::PARAM_NT);
$performsq3->execute();
unset($sql3);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `$sql1` you have 18 parameters, but in `$performsql1` you have only 17 bindings. You have lost 1 value to bind.

**Upd.**

You have `WHERE id_faktury=:id_faktury'` - it's 18th parameter. You have lost value ':id_faktury' to bind.

Comment: i check and i havegot equally 17 parameters in sql1 and performsql1

Comment: @JohnyRlk, I have updated my answer. Can you check it?

Comment: now i see but i this where work like to witch id_faktury update? and  need this only to find what element i want update?

Comment: @JohnyRlk, you still need it to put into `bindValue(` like others parameters.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\faktury-styczeń\edytuj_fakture.php:95 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\faktury-styczeń\edytuj_fakture.php(95): PDOStatement->bindValue(':id_nabywcy', '1', 1) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\faktury-styczeń\edytuj_fakture.php on line 95

Comment: i did what you said but it's still th same error, but in the line 95$performsql1->bindValue(':id_nabywcy',$id_nabywcy, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$performsql2->execute();
unset($sql2);

Comment: @JohnyRlk, you have also forget to bind `:id_nabywcy` like this `bindValue(':id_nabywcy'...`

Comment: @JohnyRlk , you have the same issue for a second $sql2 query. Just do the same check for second query.

Comment: i know i add this last parametr to sql3 and sql2

Comment: and now error show n this line with new add paragraf

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Comment: Can you update your question and add full error stacktrace?

Comment: i made really stupid mistake i do nto chnage performsql1 when i use it for sql2 and sql3